# Signing android app manually doesn't work properly

Tags: android, google-play, signing

I developed a Android App and could sign it with the Eclipse Plugin, but i wanted to sign it manually with jarsigner and zipalign, so that i can choose the algorithm and the keysize by my self.

I created a Keystore with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore keystore_name -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

My first issue is that i cant enter the Keystore with the Eclipse Plugin. It says:

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

So i went on with the jarsigner like this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore keystore_name  my_application.apk alias_name
```

and it works fine.
finally i run the tool zipaling:

```
zipalign -v 4 inputfile.apk outputfile.apk
```

I could publish my app in the market without any trouble. But when a friend downloaded my app, he gets the error: `Package file was not signed correctly`

Furthermore I can't install my app signed manually. But the version, signed with the Eclipse plugin works fine.

The big problem now I have is, that I can't upload the new apk file do the market, because it says that it is signed with an other certificate.
What can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried signing other apps to see if the same thing happens? Have you tried the DSA encryption method to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: no i did not, but my problem is, that i have a corrupt app in my account and couldnt make it works, because its not properly signed and i cant upload a new signed version which works

Comment: ok i could solve 1 problem. the & symbol is not allowed in the password. without this symbol, i can enter my keystore with the Eclipse Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I came across a similar issue before. After trying a few things I used jarsigner like this and it has been working fine:

```
jarsigner -verbose -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA -keystore %path to key store here% -signedjar %the name you want for your signed apk here% %the apk you want to sign here% your.keystore
```

EDIT:

Just noticed your question was about what to do with the app on the market place. I'm no help there. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the `keytool` you are using:

```
which keytool
```

check if it is set to openjdk... Android supports only Sun/Oracle Java as the keytool.